# Storing a image in Django file-system (without using a database)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-media

index.html

```
<form method="POST" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ image_form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search via Image">
</form>
```

forms.py

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.Form):
    image_field = forms.ImageField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get('submit') == 'Search via Image':
        print(request.POST)
        print(request.FILES)
```

So I want to take the image uploaded by the user and save it in my storage, perform a few operations on it, display it on the webpage and delete it. But I am not being able to go this.
In request.POST I'm getting a dict containing the file name, but that's plain text. And while using request.FILES I'm getting,

```
<MultiValueDict: {}>
```

How should I go about this? Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to this:

```
<form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
   {{ image_form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search via Image">
</form>
```

You are missing [enctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype) in your form.

Comment: you are using form in your view, can you show code related to form from your view?

Comment: I've added the forms.py code. Before saving or doing any other operations I wanted to see the requests and files I'm receiving. So that I can actually know that I've got the file to do further operations like saving the image etc.